# Calculating a circular area using Lat/Long as a point in the middle with radius of any length using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

If I have the latitude and longitude of a specific location and I need to return all of the towns/cities that are within a certain distance of this location e.g. **1 to 500** miles as text on a webpage. How would I do this in Javascript in conjunction with https://positionstack.com/?

[image]

[image: Sending a GET request with name of specific place to positionstack.com]

Answer (score 0):

For an exact calculation (well, [the earth is *not exacty spherical*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figure_of_the_Earth) ...) you will need to go through the spherical distance equation found here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-distance-two-points-earth

```
const [sin,cos]=["sin","cos"].map(fn=>x=>Math[fn](x/180*Math.PI)), // sin, cos in degree
  r = 3963, // earth radius in miles (in km: 6371)
  dist = r * Math.acos(sin(lat0)*sin(lat) + cos(lat0)*cos(lat)*cos(long-long0))
```

So, you would have to calculate the distance from the centre point for potential lat/long pair in order to determine whether the distance is smaller or larger than 500 miles.

```js
const places=[
 ["Ottawa",45.43026089850648, -75.70148893316303],
 ["Montreal",45.523098477377275, -73.63711795099447],
 ["Montpelier,VT",44.25960673881783, -72.58589897991801],
 ["Charleston,SC",32.781829336634694, -79.95973326005715],
 ["Atlanta,GA",33.76477968890186, -84.39589310326373]],
  lat0=38.8977597229071, long0=-77.03654054271286,             // White House coords.
  r=3963,                                                      // earth's radius
  [sin,cos]=["sin","cos"].map(fn=>x=>Math[fn](x/180*Math.PI)), // sin(deg), cos(deg)
  sinlat0=sin(lat0),coslat0=cos(lat0),
  showDist=(place,lat,long)=>{
   const dist = r * Math.acos(sinlat0*sin(lat) + coslat0*cos(lat)*cos(long-long0))
   console.log(place,dist.toFixed(2));
}
  
console.log("Distances from the White House (in miles):");
places.forEach(p=>showDist(...p));

console.log("\nOr, taking output from https://positionstack.com:");
const d={"data":[{"latitude":40.68295,"longitude":-73.9708,"type":"locality","name":"New York","number":null,"postal_code":null,"street":null,"confidence":1,"region":"New York","region_code":"NY","county":"Kings County","locality":"New York","administrative_area":null,"neighbourhood":null,"country":"United States","country_code":"USA","continent":"North America","label":"New York, NY, USA"},{"latitude":40.777048,"longitude":-73.967596,"type":"borough","name":"Manhattan","number":null,"postal_code":null,"street":null,"confidence":1,"region":"New York","region_code":"NY","county":"New York County","locality":"New York","administrative_area":null,"neighbourhood":null,"country":"United States","country_code":"USA","continent":"North America","label":"Manhattan, New York, NY, USA"},{"latitude":40.775105,"longitude":-73.968777,"type":"county","name":"New York County","number":null,"postal_code":null,"street":null,"confidence":0.4,"region":"New York","region_code":"NY","county":"New York County","locality":null,"administrative_area":null,"neighbourhood":null,"country":"United States","country_code":"USA","continent":"North America","label":"New York County, NY, USA"}]};

d.data.forEach(p=>showDist(p.name,p.latitude,p.longitude))
```